# Como deixar o NodeJS rodando como serviço?

Tags: node.js

Estava dando uma pesquisada por aqui e encontrei apenas soluções para `linux`, deixar o servidor rodando pelo `dos` não é nada seguro, pois a qualquer momento poderá haver uma queda.

A questão é, existe algum método para deixar o `NodeJS` rodando como `serviço`? E caso o servidor caia, existe uma forma dele "restartar" automaticamente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução para isso chama-se : **Windows Service**

Por padrão, o seu site Node.js ficará executando enquanto a janela do console que iniciou seu site estiver funcionando. Se você fechar ela, ou seu servidor reiniciar, já era, seu site vai ficar fora do ar até que você execute o npm start de novo.

Para que isso não aconteça, você deve instalar seu site como um **Windows Service**. Para fazer isso, primeiro instale o módulo node-windows globalmente:

```
npm install -g node-windows
```

Agora rode o seguinte comando (dentro da pasta do seu projeto) para incluir uma referência deste módulo ao seu projeto:

```
npm link node-windows
```

Depois, dentro do seu projeto Node.js (na raiz) crie um arquivo `service.js` com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
var Service = require('node-windows').Service;

// Create a new service object
var svc = new Service({
  name:'Nome da sua Aplicação',
  description: 'Apenas uma descrição',
  script: 'C:\\domains\\sitenodejs\\bin\\www'
});

// Listen for the "install" event, which indicates the
// process is available as a service.
svc.on('install',function(){
  svc.start();
});

svc.install();
```

Troque as propriedades name e description de acordo com seu gosto, mas atente à propriedade script nesse código, que deve conter o caminho absoluto até o arquivo JS que inicia sua aplicação. No meu caso, como estou usando express, estou apontando para o arquivo www que fica na pasta bin do projeto (curiosamente ele não possui extensão, mas é um arquivo).

Se você fez tudo corretamente, vá até `Ferramentas Administrativas > Serviços (Administrative Tools > Services` ou `services.msc` no Run/Executar do Windows) e seu serviço vai aparecer lá com o name que definiu ali no script, lhe permitindo alterar suas configurações de inicialização, dar Start, Stop, etc.

Caso precise remover esse serviço (para instalar uma versão mais atualizada, por exemplo) rode o comando abaixo no `cmd`:

```
SC STOP servicename
SC DELETE servicename
```

Espero que ajude :)